# $(...).functionName() is not a function - Why it occurs and how to avoid this?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting the console error

> $(...).functionName() is not a function

This is my function call

```
$("button").functionName();
```

This is my function

```
$.fn.functionName = function() {
       //Do Something
}(jQuery);
```

Why this error comes and how to avoid this error?

Comment: It's because you've randomly added `(jQuery)` to your code, as if you're expecting to have an IIFE, although the syntax isn't correct. Remove that and your code works fine.

Comment: This usually happen when you have an IIFE followed by a function call. If should look like this: `(function(){...})()init();` Try adding `;` before and after IIFE

Answer (score 0):

try using the following syntax:

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
    functionName: function () {

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `(jquery)` from your code,

```js
$.fn.functionName = function() {
       //Do Something
       alert('worked');
};

$("button").functionName();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button>Button</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.fn.functionName = function() {
       //Do Something
}(jQuery);
```

This is an self-invoking functions. The benefit of self-invoking functions is that it enables you to execute code once without cluttering the global namespace (without declaring any globals).

```js
$.fn.functionName = function() {
  alert('Immediately Invoked');
}(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button> Button </button>
```

If you run the previous code snippet, it will automatically invoke the function and `alert the message` without calling the function.

---

To fix the problem you need to remove the (jQuery) so you can use the function:

```js
$.fn.functionName = function() {
    this.css('color', 'red');
}
 
$( "button" ).functionName();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Button 1</button>
<button>Button 2</button>
```